Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop')- Jest Unit test case giving error
I have written the following code in my vue3 project. when i checking jest code coverage then console showing following error.
Also when i run the application normally,code is working properly.
enter image description here
my Unit test case code details
helloWorld.vue
<style>
@import "bootstrap";
</style>
<script lang="ts">
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Hello World!",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getName1(e) {
      var status1: any = [];
      const _target = e?.target;
      if (_target?.value === "all") {
        console.log("all", _target);
        status1 = _target?.checked ? ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "all"] : []; // set all values in the array
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    let deleteRequestModal = new bootstrap.Modal(
      document.getElementById("myModal")
    );
    deleteRequestModal.show();
  },
};
</script>
<template>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="myModal"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">...</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
            Close
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

jest config file
module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "ts", "json", "vue"],
  transform: {
    "^.+.js$": "babel-jest",
    ".*.(vue)$": "@vue/vue3-jest",
    "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^axios$": "axios/dist/node/axios.cjs",
    "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>test.js",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!@vueform/multiselect)"],

  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testMatch: ["**/src/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"],
  testTimeout: 30000,
  verbose: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "src/**/*.{js,vue,ts}",
    "!src/main.js", // No need to cover bootstrap file
  ],
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      babelConfig: "babel.config.js",
    },
  },
};

Please help me to resolve this
